# How to check statistical significance for ranking promotions to customers?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

**Context:**
As part of Marketing Optimisation, our client wants us to develop a machine learning model that can score the promotions for each of its customers. Based on the scores, the promotions will be sorted and only top promotions will be communicated to the customer. The promotions can be discounts or just informational. Our client wants to know that the scores for promotions from the model for each customer differ significantly.

Here is the requirement from client:
*"Need to be able to identify if the difference in 2 promotions for a customer is statistically significant (if Promotions P1 and P2 are ranked 1 and 2 for Customer C1 there should be a mechanism to understand if the difference is significant)"*

**Question:**
How to verify the difference in the scores for any two promotions for a customer is statistically significant?

**My approach:**
Here is the approach, I have in mind for the above question.
1) Build, say, 30 different models using random samples from training data to score the promotions for each customer.
2) Do hypothesis testing using two-sample t-test
H0: S1-S2 > 0
Ha: S1-S2 <= 0
where, S1 and S2 are averages of scores from 30 models(as in point 1) for promotions P1 and P2 for a customer.

Based on the p-value for test statistic, which was calculated under the assumption that Null-hypothesis is true, I can accept or reject null-hypothesis.

Is my approach correct?
Is there a better way to do it (without the need to build 30 models)?

**Note:** I have only minimal theoretical knowledge on hypothesis testing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, if you need more information or my explanation above is unclear, please ask.

Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the question, I am not sure if the question is still unclear. Please comment on a specific part of the question that is unclear to you.

Comment: How do you assign rankings to the promotions for a customer?

Comment: For each customer, promotions can be ranked by sorting them by scores, which would be obtained from ML model.